# Detect any change in certain sheet triggered from google sheets apps script refresh

Tags: api, google-apps-script, google-sheets, telegram

I currently have a bunch of api calls using importjson(), I have set it to refresh these calls daily and link certain values from these set of api calls to an aggregated sheet. Is there a way to listen to and detect value changes on the aggregated sheet so I can send that change to a telegram bot? I have tried onChange() but it seems like that only works when the sheet is open, whereas I'd like to be able to have it run in the background, as the API call schedule is also in the background.

Currently my onChange() function is as such, but as mentioned above it won't work once i close the sheet

```js
function setUpTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('logChanges')
  .forSpreadsheet('1_2EpKzgDMHK59OOAslsd1LOwsH7Wtn7Zc5pwR-wbo')
  .onChange()
  .create();
}

function logChanges(e) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Changes');
  const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, 1, 3).setValues([
    [e.source.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange().offset(0,-5).getValue(),
     e.source.getSheetName(),
     e.source.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange().getValue()]
  ]);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but I believe the problem is that `onChange`, as well as `onEdit`, doesn't work well on automated cell updates, meaning it requires a manual change/edit for it to trigger. There may be some workarounds for it, though.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately neither a GAS script or an API call makes the triggers run.

From the Apps Script Documentation:

> Script executions and API requests do not cause triggers to run. For example, calling `FormResponse.submit()` to submit a new form response does not cause the form's submit trigger to run.

As an alternative solution, you can create a trigger that launches a function every X minutes. This would be a possible configuration:

###### `Code.gs`

```js
ScriptApp.newTrigger("logChanges")
  .timeBased()
  .everyMinutes(5)
  .create();
```

###### `Using UI`

[image: Configuration for Time Drive Trigger]

###### Documentation

- [Simple Triggers Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions)
- [Installable Triggers Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#restrictions)